# IntelliJ IDEA is not finding Play Twirl templates (sometimes)

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

I'm developing a Play Java 2.4.x application that's pretty much following all the Play conventions.

When viewing the project in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, the Twirl templates are usually marked as "cannot resolve symbol" in the import statements. Sometimes and inexplicably (to me), they will show up ok.

I can ctrl-click on any of the templates and IDEA will show me the compiled Scala file. Even if they are marked as "cannot resolve"

For instance, this screenshot shows a few templates as ok, but others not:
[image]

The templates are in `/app/views/**.scala.html`

Twirl compiles them to `/target/scala-2.11/twirl/main/views/html/**.template.scala`

And Scala compiles them to `/target/scala-2.11/classes/views/html/**.class`

I am running IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.3.4 with Playframework support plugin version 1.0

`sbt run` works perfectly fine on this project and has never complained about the missing templates.

Here is my sources configuration (most of that seems to be autogenerated, I've tried cleaning it up, but something keeps adding all the ones in red back in)
[image]

Comment: IntelliJ will only be able to find views after they have been compiled, that might be one reason.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't show that, but the class files for the templates are in /target/scala-2.11/classes/views/html

Comment: There are some [open issues](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL?q=Twirl%20%23unresolved) for Twirl support. [SCL-10578](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10578) looks related to your problem.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder. That seems to be my exact issue.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @NateH06 It seems to be a hard to reproduce issue, so the bug is still open. For me, the latest IntelliJ versions seem to have fixed this.

Comment: Good to note and thanks. This happened to me after an IntelliJ update, which included a Play update, so go figure. I managed to solve it by going into IntelliJ File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open bug which looks like your problem:

- [SCL-10578](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10578) 2012.2: Cannot resolve symbol on twirl template import